# What's the word for describing days/months/years when comparing to something else?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english

Here's an example of the sentence I'm trying to write:

"Monday: the (x) equivalent of falling down a flight of stairs"

Some examples of other sentences that are similar to the one I'm trying to create:

Aloe vera: the botanical equivalent of drinking milk after eating a hot pepper

Moses: the biblical equivalent of a water bender

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: *Calendrical*, perhaps?

Comment: @michael.hor257k in the sense that Monday is a day that appears on a calendar, that could work. I'm just trying to find a word with the definition of, "of or relating to a day/a day of the week." I can't seem to get away from the word "daily" (ex. "the daily equivalent of falling down a flight of stairs") but the definitions don't match at all.

Comment: Well, Monday only occurs once a week - so in that sense it would be a *weekly* experience. The thing is that your other examples are much wider. And if this is supposed to be funny, then *calendrical* works a little better - though not by much.

Comment: First of all, you could use *temporal*. However, the analogy itself doesn't work. The only reason that "Monday is like falling down a flight of stairs" is because it's the first day back to work. So it really has nothing to do with *time* but more to do with *employment* (e.g., *the* ***job*** *equivalent of . . .*)

Comment: What is a "water bender"?

Comment: I would say "chronillogical", but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Daily, weekly, yearly, annual - temporal.

Comment: can you find some example usages of any of these examples that are close to how the OP want to use these examples? Adding them would make this a better answer.

Comment: This is a poorly expressed answer. The question asks for "the word" - i.e. one single word - but you've provided *five* words, of which just one (**temporal**) suits what the OP is asking for. I recommend you [edit] your answer to (a) clarify what your solution is, (b) provide an explanation of *why* it's correct, (c) provide an authoritative source such as a dictionary definition to support your reason, and (d) ideally, add a link to that source. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of options, depending on the effect you're after:

- "[Calendrical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calendrical)" – Insofar as you're aiming to be able to cover days, months, and years, this is technically most correct. While most English readers would intuit its relation to "calendar", the word itself is not commonly used.
- "[Temporal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temporal)" – This word is much more common than calendrical, but also doesn't indicate anything specific human schedules (that is, the calendar); time would exist even if the calendar didn't.
- "[Schedular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schedular)" – In your particular example, the key to the analogy is the place that Mondays play in the modern Western schedule: They mark the end of leisure time and the start of work time. As such, "schedular" may be a good option. Similar to calendrical, most would grasp its relation to "schedule", however it also is not commonly used.
- "[Chronological](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chronological)" – More commonly used than some of the other options, but also is typically used to describe time specifically in the past, as opposed to the present or future.
- "[Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)" – This one is a bit of a stretch, but the Gregorian calendar is the one most English speakers are familiar with (even though they may not be familiar with the name).
- "[Routine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/routine)" – This one focuses less specifically on the time and calendar aspect, but is effective because Mondays are all about the routine of going back to work. It also adds some humor due to the implication that falling down stairs could be part of a routine.

Here's a comparison of these words' use, if you want to optimize for familiarity: [Ngrams trends](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calendrical%2Cschedular%2Cgregorian%2Cchronological%2Ctemporal%2Croutine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalendrical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschedular%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgregorian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchronological%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctemporal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croutine%3B%2Cc0)